# Jmeter report analysis

Tags: jmeter, performance

How can I analyse the Jmeter report?
what are the standard data for application having good performance to compare with?

Comment: Every application and its target audience is different and so its performance goal. You should go through this link first and if you still have some issues regarding JMeter results, please ask that specific issue in a different post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14252570/how-to-analyse-jmeter-result

Comment: Thanks for the comment Dhiman. I need more help on the process to analyse Jmeter result.

Comment: Try Loadosophia for analyzing JMeter results. It generates some very good reports which help a lot in analysis.

Comment: I integrated Loadsophia in my test plan. The graph they generate are very attractive but I didn't understand to analyse them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you go on to do performance testing you need to define benchmarks& objectives of your performance testing. There could be variety of goals for any performance testing activity.

For example, we can perform a performance test to identify the breakpoint of application or the maximum number of users application can handle with reasonable response time.

In an alternative case, we can have a requirement to just analyze the server resource utilization under different user loads.

Some time performance tests are also used to analyze the changes in application performance after some code changes or hardware changes. In such cases we should have base line results (i.e results before & after changes so a comparison can be done)

So in short it all depends upon requirements. If you are new to performance testing and have a real time project to do then first of all you need to clarify the requirements, goals and objectives of performance test.

Last but not least, you can use JMeter Plugins or Loadosophia Service to get good graphical reports from JMeter data.

Answer (score 0):

To analyze the report you must first get a tad familiar with performance related terms like throughput etc. I would suggest you to add the Summary Report listener to get a better view of your application's performance. The error % column in the Summary report needs to be zero throughout to ensure that your application is performing at-least.

There is no such standards and depends what are your expectations from the application. Try to analyze what amount of traffic you want to handle and then prepare your script accordingly.

Thanks!